# Julia interrupt model solver and resume it

Tags: model, julia, interrupt, solver, gurobi

I'm running an optimization problem on Atom, using Julia.

The solver I use is Gurobi:

```
m=Model(solver=GurobiSolver())
...
solve(m)
```

My model may need hours to days of computation to reach the optimal value, so I would like to know if I can do the following when solve() is running :

```
1. Interrupt upon interrupting/stopping Julia
2. Interrupt if the objective function returns a sufficiently good result
3. Interrupt after a set time
```

and then display and save the current state reached so I can resume the computation later.

Comment: I don't think you can. You would need to save the whole tree. Cplex used to have something called endtree/starttree but that option was dropped. On unix you may be able to save the process and restart using something like CRIU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set SolutionLimit or TimeLimit as GurobiSolver parameters

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer:

That's very broad and misses a lot of details why mentioning things which do not matter (Atom as Editor).

Also: consider this as educated guess.

### Can do

- display something and wait in terminal
- continue after user-input

This should be easily achievable by defining a callback, which goes through your conditions and act according to these (e.g. waiting some seconds or for user-input).

There is one thing to decide on: Gurobi's [Callback Codes](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/callback_codes.html) of types **where**, which will decide when your callback is called.

For going through your conditions, you will want to use the values for **what** (see above docs).

Viable candidates:

```
POLLING 0   Periodic polling callback
MIPSOL  4   Found a new MIP incumbent
```

Now **polling** will in general not allow you to query *what* values. This makes it pretty useless for your task and we won't consider it. The only advantage is that it's probably very frequently called, without a potentially huge variance of times between calls.

**MIPSOL** would allow you to get access to the interesting variables like *MIP_OBJBST* (current best objective) and co.

The core assumption here: Gurobi has no callback-timelimit and kills off your callback (safeguard-like). I don't think there is something like that (at least not without a warning in the docs)!

### Cannot do

In general, you [can't](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/ctDasw1B1FU) save the whole state of Gurobi (link applies to Gurobi 7). From a software-engineering-based standpoint, it's not too surprising (not impossible, but potentially tricky).

### Can do

You can turn-off your computer (**hibernation!**), while solving or while being in some waiting-state in your callback. Now i will say it again: we are talking about [Hibernation of Operating-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)). Either a suspend-to-ram (PC will use less energy) or suspend-to-disk (completely off).

**Now:**

- this will destroy internal-timings (which you can observe in the verbose output)

  - not sure if relevant for you (maybe in interaction with your callback!)
  - warning: **i could imagine** that there are some statistics / interactive-learning based heuristic decisions (approach A worked in this part of the tree good; do A again) based on **timings** (as operations are harder to count)

    - it's not impossible that those statistics are completely taken off-balance by hibernation!
- this depends in it's core on your Operating-sytem
- this is probably not guaranteed to work or recommended by the Gurobi-devs, but might work (and does run; but it's harder to evaluate the impact on the solution-process)

  - we already saw, that things might change during sleep (time) and assumptions on these things are the potential problem

### Can do

Using callbacks and queries on internal-states as mentioned above, you can use your own kind of serialization to outsource the current best solution and maybe more.

These things, the most important being the [MIP start vector](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/start.html) you can later use for a completely newly started optimization-process.

You need to decide on how to serialize this data. Database, HDF5, Text-files and co.!

Reading out and Reusing should follow Gurobi's docs.

**Now:**

- starting from a feasible MIP-solution (your best found yet) is not as good as reusing the whole internal state (we are losing a lot of solving-process dependent information)

  - but it should help a lot in general (probably depends much on the problem itself)
- you can try to store and re-add the objective-bound as constraint, but i don't think it will help much

Comment: I found that using the parameters SolutionLimit and TimeLimit do what I was looking for